# Relation between Exterior derivative of a section and a Connection on the Vector bundle

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Let we have a vector bundle over a manifold $p : E \rightarrow M$ and there is a section $s$ on it and also $\nabla$ is a connection on this vector bundle. Is there any relation between $ds : TM \rightarrow TE$ (as an exterior derivative of a map between two manifolds) and $\nabla s$ i.e if $X$ is a vector field on $M$, then is there a relation between $ds(X)$ and $\nabla_X s$?
Any reference will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A connection on $E$ determines a splitting of the tangent bundle $TE = H\oplus V$, where for each $q\in E$, $V_q$ is the ***vertical tangent space at $\boldsymbol q$*** (the tangent space to the fiber $E_q$ through $q$) and $H_q$ is a complementary subspace called the ***horizontal tangent space at $\boldsymbol q$***. The vertical space is defined independently of any choice of connection, while the horizontal space is defined in terms of the connection as follows: Given any smooth curve $\gamma:I\to M$ (where $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ is an interval), a ***section of $\boldsymbol E$ along $\boldsymbol \gamma$*** is a lift of $\gamma$ to $E$, i.e., a curve $\sigma\colon I\to E$ such that $p\circ \sigma = \gamma$, which is to say that $\sigma(t) \in E_{\gamma(t)}$ for each $t\in I$. A section $\sigma$ along $\gamma$ is a ***horizontal lift*** if it is parallel along $\gamma$: $D_t \sigma(t) \equiv 0$ (where $D_t$ is the covariant differentiation along $\gamma$ determined by $\nabla$). A vector $w\in T_qE$ is said to be ***horizontal*** (with respect to $\nabla$) if it is the velocity vector of a horizontal lift of some curve.

The decomposition $TE = V\oplus H$ determines a linear bundle map $\pi_V\colon TE\to V$ called ***vertical projection***, which for each $q\in E$ is just the projection from $T_qE$ to $V_q$ with kernel $H_q$.

Given a section $s$ of $E$ and a vector field $X\in \mathfrak X(M)$, the relation between $ds(X)$ and $\nabla_X s$ is
$$
\nabla_X s = \pi_V(ds(X)).
$$

Comment: But $p_\ast (\nabla_ X s) = X$ and since $p_\ast (ds(X)) = X$ (i.e $p_\ast(H) = 0$), shouldn't it be better to just alternate the names of the vertical and horizontal vectors of tangent space of $E$?

Comment: @SubhankarD.: I'm not sure what you mean by this. The value of $\nabla_X s$ at a point $q\in M$ is an element of the fiber $E_q$, which we can identify with a vertical tangent vector (since the tangent space to the vector space $E_q$ is canonically identified with $E_q$ itself). Since the restriction of $p$ to $E_q$ is constant, $p_*v=0$ for every vertical vector $v$. In particular, $p_*(\nabla_X s) = 0$.  The reason for the terms "horizontal" and "vertical" is by analogy with the case $E = \mathbb R^2$ and $M=\mathbb R$, with $p(x,y) = x$.

Comment: I realized I was wrong actually and your explanation totally makes sense to me now. Thank you.